# Upper and lower limit from list of list

Tags: python, list

Say, I have a list of lists:

```
L1 = [[1.5,2.5],[3.5,4.5]]
```

and I want to set lower and upper limits with the elements in it.

In the case above, 1.5 being the lower limit and 3.5 being the upper limit and also applies to 2.5 being the lower limit and 4.5 being the upper limit.

```
L1 = [[1.5,2.5],[3.5,4.5]]
for i in L1:
    upperLimit = i[1][0]
    lowerLimit = i[0][0]
```

I get an error saying float object is not subscriptable. I'm not familiar with list operation itself and would like to hear opinions on this problem of mine.

Once I set them as lower limits and upper limits respectively, I can proceed to perform comparisons in the later stage but for now, I'm wondering how could I do this?

Comment: `upperLimit = i[1]` etc. No need for `[0]`

Comment: Even better, you don't need the `for` loop, it's just a small list, just those 2 statements are enough, but if the list is dynamic; then you've to improve the loop even more.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is looping through `L1` and making `i` equal to the sub-list it is currently on.  For example, if your `print(i)` in the loop, it will display:

```
[1.5, 2.5]
[3.5, 4.5]
```

When you do `upperLimit = i[1][0]`, you are trying to access an index inside a float... which isn't accepted.
You just need to do:

```
L1 = [[1.5,2.5],[3.5,4.5]]
for i in L1:
    upperLimit = i[1]
    lowerLimit = i[0]
```